# if statement not working in cron

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, raspberry-pi2

I have the following code: (record.sh)

```
cd $(dirname $0)

dt=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');
echo $dt;
read action < /home/nfs/sauger/web/pi/action.txt
echo $action;
if [[ $action == *"start"* ]]
then
  echo "start recording"
  ./gone.sh
  exit 1
elif [[ $action == *"stop"* ]]
then
 echo "stop recording"
  ./gone.sh
  exit 1
else 
#More stuff done here
fi
```

When I run this script manually the output is the following:

```
19/01/2016 19:07:11
start
start recording
```

If the same script is run via a (root) cronjob, the output is the following:

```
19/01/2016 19:07:01
start
```

As you can see, the file "action.txt" has been read without a problem ("start" is logged both times) so this should not be an issue of permissions or wrong paths. But when run as a cronjob, the if-statement is not called. No "start recording" appears.

So my question is: Why does the if-statement work when I call the script manually, but not when this is done via cron?

Comment: Are you sure it's being executed with the same shell both times?

Comment: Show first line (with shebang) of your script and add your cron line to your question.

Comment: Yup. This absolutely looks like a script being run with `/bin/sh` when it's written for bash.

Comment: @Cyrus the first line is "cd"... so. Yes you (all) might be right with your suggestion :)

Comment: BTW, when working with cron jobs, it is always a good idea to also check the stderr. In you case, you should have received an error message to stderr which would have pinpointed the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your script is written for bash; these errors are almost certainly indicative of it being run with `/bin/sh` instead.

Either add an appropriate shebang and ensure that it's being called in a way that honors it (`/path/to/script` rather than `sh /path/to/script`), or fix it to be compatible. For instance:

```
case $action in
  *start*)
    echo "start recording"
    ./gone.sh
    exit 1
    ;;
  *stop*)
    echo "stop recording"
    ./gone.sh
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: yes, this was the issue.. thanks a tonn..! We need to add the apprpriate shebang .. :)